# What's the changes after multiple playthroughs of You Must Build A Boat?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

The ace level increases and the games supposedly gets harder. Are there other changes from one playthrough to the other?

The only thing I found so far was a figurehead for my boat in the garden.

Answer (score 1):

Agnetti decorates your ship depending on how many Ace levels you have. So far, for 2 Aces (i.e. restart the game for the first time), she puts up a figurehead and for 3 Aces, she turns the walls of the ship into metal sheets.

I daresay she does other stuff for mor Ace levels but I haven't got there yet.